# How to make Live Camera Preview in Android

Tags: android, camera, preview

I've looked for tutorials on how to do this but everything I've found uses the deprecated Camera class. Can anybody point me to good resources on how I can show a live camera preview in my app? Or possibly show me some example code with the bare minimum needed to pull up a live preview of the camera?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Comment: Yes i developed the same apps and work correctly. The functionality of the apps are to take five picture on one click. And save it in the picture folder.
But the source code are very large so visit to the below links. In this site source code for three apps are present and solve your problem easily. thank you [How to to developed live preview camera or Custom Camera application](https://androidze.wordpress.com/)